# Postgresql Trigger updating entire column instead of specific rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I'm trying to achieve is, as I execute an UPDATE statement I want the TRIGGER to update every row that has **insurance_team = 'professional'** and **expiration_date = current_date**, just make the expiration year +1.

My current TRIGGER function though updates the entire column.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_premiums (
    contract_code text NOT NULL,
    insurance_team text NOT NULL,
    starting_date date NOT NULL,
    expiration_date date NOT NULL,
    contract_cost float8 NOT NULL,
    vehicle_contract text NOT NULL,
    customer_contract text NOT NULL,
    driver_contract text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT insurance_premiums_pkey PRIMARY KEY (contract_code)
);
```

**Trigger**

```
create trigger update_contract after
update
    on
    public.insurance_premiums for each row execute function new_date()
```

**Trigger Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_date()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN 
        if old.insurance_team = 'professional' then
            if old.expiration_date = CURRENT_DATE then
                new.expiration_date = old.expiration_date + integer '365';
                update insurance_premiums set expiration_date = new.expiration_date;
            end if;
        end if;
        return new;
    END;
$function$
;
```

**Update example**

```
UPDATE insurance_premiums 
SET contract_cost = 736.33
WHERE contract_code = 'EI-36653';
```

**INSERT** of the above example:

```
INSERT INTO insurance_premiums (contract_code, insurance_team, starting_date, expiration_date, contract_cost, vehicle_contract, customer_contract, driver_contract) 
VALUES('EI-36653', 'professional', '2019-03-31', '2021-06-24', 12736.3, 'Sprinter', 'Antoine Burgise', 'Prudence Lacer');
```

Sidenote: the above update statement is just an example to test the trigger.

Comment: Lose the `update insurance_premiums ...` part. You have already set the `new.expiration_date` for that row. Your `UPDATE` has no `WHERE` to limit it to a specific row and is redundant anyway.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver If I remove the update query from the function then it doesn't update anything. For the where part I thought that the if statements had me covered.

Comment: Use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an UPDATE at all.

Define the trigger as `before update` trigger:

```
create trigger update_contract 
  BEFORE updateupdate
  on public.insurance_premiums 
  for each row execute function new_date()
```

Then the assignment `new.expiration_date := ..` is enough:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_date()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN 
  if old.insurance_team = 'professional' AND old.expiration_date = CURRENT_DATE then
    new.expiration_date := old.expiration_date + integer '365'; --<<< this is enough
  end if;
  return new;
END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: That was my bad I didn't use the := operator instead i used the = operator and that's why it didn't work, so I used the update statement. But this only works if I execute an update query on a contract from that specific category. For example if I update a contract from category 'semi' then it doesn't update every contract that belongs to the 'professional' category. Since I use `for each row` I thought that it would affect others too. Am I wrong?

Comment: For purposes of setting a variable `:=` and `=` are the same, see [assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT).  You really need to spend some time reading this [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) and in particular this [trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and this [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: @bokos21: the trigger will fire once for each row that was changed. So the trigger _function_ will be called for every row that your UPDATE changed. `:=` and `=` are the same in PL/pgSQL - I just use `:=` because I always used it (and there was a time when the assignment using `=` was discouraged)